# Label points at regular interval using qgis

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a point shapefile with a point index. Like the first picture. 
[image: Label for each point.]

I'm trying to label the point index every 30 points to obtain the second screen capture.
I also have an attribute R3 or R4 to differentiate the red and green group of points that could be used.
[image: Result wanted]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the labels tab of the layer properties, use an expression as the label field.  Do this by clicking the curly 'E' at the top next to the field selector drop-down box.

When the expression dialog opens use a conditional statement based on a modulus function something along these lines:

```
CASE WHEN "point_index" % 30 = 0 THEN "point_index" END
```

Comment: I'm close to what I need. With your formula I'm displaying the multiple of 30, is it possible to add an +11 offset?

Comment: I did it with: CASE WHEN   ( "Number"  - 11) % 30 = 0 THEN  "Number"  END

Comment: I was just editing my post to show that! +1 for beating me to it :)

Comment: You could also get fancy and use a similar approach to colour your labels red and green (HINT: look for the curly 'E' next to the colour option in the Text tab in labels - note all the other curly 'E' buttons and you can see the extent to which you can have data-driven labels and symbols).